# Why does internet get disconnected after I change mac in Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, mac-address

I have written this script to change my mac in Kali Linux:

```
ifconfig eth0|grep HWaddr
ifconfig eth0 down&&macchanger -r eth0&&ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig eth0|grep HWaddr
```

The problem is each time I do this internet gets disconnected even though I am doing `ifconfig eth0 up` after changing mac. Then I have to go to the double computer icon and open the drop down menu to click on Wired Connection 1 to reconnect to internet. Why is this happening? What command do I need to add to this script to reconnect to internet without using GUI?

Comment: ARe you sure macchanger -r eth0 is returning 0? Otherwise, the shell won't be executing `ifconfig eth0 up`

Answer (score 1):

It is the equivelant of disabling the inet device like so

$ ifconfig eth0 down

Then changing the hwaddr property to something else and bringing the device back online like so

$ ifconfig eth0 up

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out (dont know if it works for virtual machines):

1. `$ifconfig eth0 down and/or ifconfig wlan0 down`
2. `$service network-manager stop`
3. `$macchanger -r eth0 and/or macchanger -r wlan0`
4. `$service network-manager restart`

note: i dont turn the `ifconfig wlan0` or `eth0` up, because when you restart the network manager they work, but in case it turn them up manually with `ifconfig eth0` up or some jazz like that it doesnt work for me. you can check that both network interfaces work by typing `$ifconfig` (you can also see your new random MAC address).

`$` - means the coding started
`eth0` - network interface
`wlan0` - network interface
macchanger - alters the MAC address
`ifconfig` - you should know that

Answer (score -2):

'This will always happen because you're messing on the network device you are using to connect to the Internet, so it is perfectly normal that occur whenever you perform a change of this level "*of harder*" on a device disconnects "*part of the game!* "...